# Directly use c++ stream buffer

Tags: c++, stream

This is intended as an improved version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61321441/directly-use-c-stream-buffer-to-e-g-decompress). I hope I succeeded in making my question clearer with an example.

The following program will stream a text file and print its contents:

```
size_t constexpr Buffer_size = 8;

char my_buffer[Buffer_size];

std::ifstream stream("text.txt");

for (; stream;) {
    stream.read(my_buffer, Buffer_size)
    std::cout.write(my_buffer, stream.gcount());
}

// output
// Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In mi risus, eleifend ac sapien sed, sollicitudin auctor neque.
```

As far as I can tell the stream will have an internal buffer that it fills, after which blocks are copied into `my_buffer`. `my_buffer` is only used briefly, in this case to print, before it is overwritten again.

My question is, whether it is possible to use the streams internal buffer to do such temporary operations. This programs comes close, but the output is not quite right.

```
size_t constexpr Buffer_size = 8;

char my_buffer[Buffer_size];

std::ifstream stream;
stream.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(my_buffer, Buffer_size);
stream.open("text.txt");

for (; stream;) {
    stream.peek();
    std::cout.write(my_buffer, Buffer_size);
    stream.ignore(Buffer_size);
}

// output
// Lorem i.psum do.lor sit. amet, .consect.etur ad.ipiscin. In mi .risus, .eleifen.d ac sa.pien se.d, soll.icitudi.r neque..
// neque..
// neque.
```

Can this idea work? Does omitting the `read()` call save a copy as I'm hoping?

EDIT:
On the other hand, consider this program:

```
size_t constexpr Buffer_size = 8;

char my_buffer_a[Buffer_size];
char my_buffer_b[Buffer_size];

std::memset(my_buffer_a, 'A´, Buffer_size);

std::ifstream stream;
stream.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(my_buffer_a, Buffer_size);
stream.open("text.txt");

for (; stream;) {
   stream.read(my_buffer_b, Buffer_size);
   std::cout.write(my_buffer_a, Buffer_size);
}

// output  
// AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA...
```

The output suggests that my_buffer_a, which is set as the internal buffer of the stream, is never touched. This means I don't understand when the internal stream buffer is actually used.

Answer (score 0):

Your program looks good to me, but you are actually using implementation dependant behavior.
You should actually save one copy, but `std::cout.write(my_buffer, Buffer_size);` would probably do a copy within `std::cout` internal buffer ([write infos](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/))

I would prefer working with OS functions to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: The `cout.write()` is only intended as an example in this case. I wanted to demonstrate that the data I need is there already, so why should it be copied. What is the implementation dependent part? Perhaps what I want cannot be done with portable stdlib functions, but I'd like to understand why.

Comment: After further research it looks like the standard state to use the buffer (implementation is not able to bypass it). So from what you wrote earlier you are actually saving a copy by doing `peek` instead of `read` but there is the same process with `write`, as it is copying the buffer to your out stream internal buffer. One solution that you could try would be to use the same buffer for both objet but you must handle the buffer position yourself.

Comment: Please ignore the output stream. I edited the question with another example. Apparently the internal buffer is not always used. Perhaps there is no unnecessary copying if you read large enough chunks at a time.

Comment: I would suggest you to try with `buffer_b` having a size lower than `buffer_a` just to see if it avoid the copy when read size is greater or equal than buffer size, I'm not sure that the behavior that you get is the standard one.

Comment: As long as the read size is larger than the internal buffer, the internal doesn't seem to be touched. At least in this simple experiment.

Comment: You could try to remove the buffer `outstream.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(nullptr, 0);` I guess the behavior is looking [like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699397/how-do-i-disable-buffering-in-fread). This behavior is apparently not defined  on cpluscplus.com but it specified that you couldn't set a `outstream.rdbuf(nullptr);`